# Call sum method

Tags: java

My first post here, I will try to be as clear as I can.

My problem is to write a sum method and call it from main method. First, user is asked to enter start-value and then steps. Then the program should sum all integers in between.

**Example** : if user fist enters 4 and then 6, the output should be 
4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 → 39

My main-method

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Startvalue: ");
int start = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Steps: ");
int finish = input.nextInt();
finish = start + finish;
```

my Sum method:

```
public static void sum(int start, int finish) {
    if (start <= finish) {
        for (int i = start; i < finish; i++) {
             int sum = start + finish;
             System.out.print(i++);
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, there is no output, but the program runs without error. 
I think there is something wrong with my loop?

Comment: Where are you calling `sum`? Please provide sample inputs and outputs

Comment: Your method needs to compute a **single** sum. So the sum variable should be declared **outside** the loop, not inside. And you really don't want to increment i a second time inside your loop, so remove that System.out.print (i++). Finally, instead of printing from the sum() method, **return** the sum that it computes. Then **call** your method from main and print what it returns.

Comment: You really should use a debugger to follow the execution of your program; it will make things much clearer.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I am very new to coding. How do i call the sum-method?

Comment: `sum(start, finish)`.

Answer (score 2):

1) You're main function doesn't run any loop

2) Your loop is indeed wrong. Read this logic

> if user fist enters 4 and then 6, the output should be 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9

Then just in your head, think about what this does, and hopefully you'll realize you never reach 7, 8, 9 **and** that you're entering steps, not a finish value, so therefore you should be able to enter 5 and 2 steps. My point is the if statement doesn't make sense

```
for (int i = 4; i < 6; i++){
```

That being said, I suggest using a while loop and you need to output the final variable outside the loop

```
// input: start and steps 
int sum = start;
while (steps > 0) {
    start += 1; 
    sum += start;
    steps--;
}
// print or return the sum
```

Finally, make sure you actually call `sum(start, finish)` with your values

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for you, Analyze what things you have missed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumWithStep {
    static int sum =0;
    public static void main( String args[] )
    { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Startvalue: ");
        int start= input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Steps: ");
        int finish= input.nextInt();
        finish = start+finish;
        sum(start,finish);
        System.out.print (sum);
    }
    public static void sum(int start, int finish){          
        if (start<=finish){ 
            for (int i = start; i < finish; i++){
                sum= sum + i; 

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you ALL for your kind help, I will read and try to understand how to solve my problem.

Comment: you are welcome @ElloMan93 ..I am also new to stack-overflow, but I get a down vote for answering to your question. WOW.

Comment: Why? However, it was not me ;) Do you have any idea how i can change the code so the product of the integers is displayed. example: if i enter 4 and then 6, the output is: 4*5*6*7*8*9= 60480?

Comment: FWIW, dumping a bunch of code saying "here, hope you understand it", is generally viewed as a low quality post. Also - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Comment: @ElloMan93 ..  inside sum function, in the for loop instead of addition do a multiplication.